# Get mapped local folder path with TFS in batch file

Tags: batch-file, tfs, cmd

I have mapped tfs folder with local folder as below

`tfs folder: $/GQS/MGT/dev/std/TestFolder`

`local folder: d:\dev\loc`

I am able to get the mapping details using tf workfold command.

Then i am parsing the result to get the local folder patch.

my question is:

Is there any command which will return me the local mapped folder path only.

Comment: Have you taken a quick look at the Workspaces https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54dkh0y3(v=vs.100).aspx command

Comment: Is there any feedback?

Comment: @kevchadders - Yes, i am using TFS workspaces command to get the mapping then parsing it to get the local folder name. But i thought that may be there are some command to get the mapped folder name directly.

Comment: @picnic4u sorry that there isn't commands like that. Maybe you could try the workaround I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no command that only returns local path. It always returns the mapping relationships including server path and local path and workspace information.

As a workaround, you could use split the result you get from the command and extract what you want.

Or you could use Powershell script which is much more convenient:

```
cd C:\...\...\

$result = & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe" workfold "$/server path" | Out-String

$arr = $result -split ": "
```

Using colon and space to split the string. Then the local path is at the $arr array.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by relying on searching mechanism. See the below example:

```
@ECHO ON
SET SOLUTION_NAME=MySolution.sln
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('DIR /s /b %SOLUTION_NAME%') DO SET "SOLUTION_PATH=%%a"
ECHO %SOLUTION_PATH%
```

%SOLUTION_PATH% will contain the full qualified file name of your solution file.